# Adding <!DOCTYPE html> to my code breaks the stickyness of my footer

Tags: html, css

Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` is breaking my CSS only sticky footer meaning that as soon as I add it, the footer does not stick to the bottom of a web page anymore.

Following is a working example without the `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Doing further tests I've noticed that when not declaring the page as HTML5 by adding the DOCTYPE statement, the div with CSS class `wrapper` is able to be stretched to take the full document height thus pushing the footer to the bottom. This is not happening when declaring the document as HTML5.

https://jsfiddle.net/muvwh4zn/

```css
        body {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        
        .navbar {
            background-color: #444;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: #444;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            min-height: 100%;
            margin-bottom: -50px;
            padding: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-white-50 text-center navbar">
                        HEADER
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <br />

            <main>
                <div class="row">
                    BODY
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="align-middle py-3 text-white-50 text-center footer">
                    FOOTER
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Please also see my own comment just below for a possible solution to this issue.

Comment: JSFiddle includes an html5 doctype by default. You can check this by clicking on the dropdown that says 'html' in the top left.

Comment: @NateLevin in fact my footer is not working in JSFiddle and I could not understand why. That's exactly the reason. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. Have tried changing the type of document to HTML 4.0 but I suppose it won't work in JSFiddle.

Comment: For anyone who might need it, as an alternative to what Sergey suggests, I found the explanation of that is needed to solve this issue in the following answer stackoverflow.com/a/33217026/5014665. In addition, to setting htmland body to height 100% (which I had done) you also need to do the same on every single immediate sibling element. In my case this would mean also setting container as having height 100%. –

Answer (score 1):

Add flexibility to the `container` class. Your footer will always be pinned to the bottom.

https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```css
        body {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: #444;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: #444;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            min-height: 100%;
            margin-bottom: -50px;
            padding: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
        }

        .push {
            height: 50px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">


</head>


<body>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="wrapper">

            <header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="align-middle py-3 text-white-50 text-center navbar">
                        header
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <br />

            <main>
                <div class="row">
                    BODY
                </div>
            </main>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="align-middle py-3 text-white-50 text-center footer">
                    FOOTER
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would you comment a bit more on your suggestion? How does adding those declarations to `container` make it more flexible.

Comment: Hello. Yes, of course I'll tell you more. You need to add a container (with flex rules) to your css class, which is listed at the very top of my answer. Your `container` class is the parent of all blocks, which means that if you set the flex rule with `flex-direction column` to this class, then all blocks will be built in a column, and in order to distribute the inner blocks along the content (horizontally), you need to set the rule `justify-content space-between` And it is obligatory to indicate the height of 100% to occupy all the space in height.

Comment: Hello. if my answer helped you, then check the box to the left of my answer pls